# Getting all values from laravel relationship table

Tags: laravel, relationship

I have below relationship in laravel model for Bills,

```
    protected $table = 'purchase_bills';
    protected $primaryKey = 'bill_id';

    public function vendors()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Vendors::class);
    }
```

Below relationship for Vendor,

```
    protected $table = 'vendors';
    protected $primaryKey = 'vendor_id';
    public function bills()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Purchasebills::class, 'bill_id');
    }
```

Now i am trying to get all bills of specific vendor with below code,

```
        $bills = Vendors::find(1)->bills()->where('vendor_id', $vendor_id);
        return Datatables::of($bills)->make();
```

But it always returns only 1 row from a table if it is first, even though there are many bills.

How can i get all bills from that vendor_id?

Comment: Can you `dd(Vendors::find(1)->bills()->get())` and see what you get?

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve the issue, actually, it was a wrong foreign key assignment in the model,
Below is correct one.

```
return $this->hasMany(Purchasebills::class, 'vendor_id');
```